# The meaning of the independent variables in prcomp formula

Tags: r, pca

I'm reading "Applied Predictive Modeling" by Kuhn and Johnson. In the code for chapter 3.3 Data Transformations for Multiple Predictors, there is a code snippet:

```
pr <- prcomp(~ AvgIntenCh1 + EntropyIntenCh1,
             data = segTrainTrans,
             scale. = TRUE)
```

Full code example [here](https://github.com/topepo/AppliedPredictiveModeling/blob/master/inst/chapters/03_Data_Pre_Processing.R#L90).

In the documentation for `prcomp`, I couldn't find much on how this first parameter is even interpreted (this `~ AvgIntenCh1 + EntropyIntenCh1` formula). It just says:

```
 formula: a formula with no response variable, referring only to
          numeric variables.
```

How is that formula used by the `prcomp` call, what does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just an alternative way of specifying which variables to run the PCA on. It seems that it's equivalent to just specifying `x` instead of a `formula`.

```r
prcomp(iris[,-5])
#> Standard deviations (1, .., p=4):
#> [1] 2.0562689 0.4926162 0.2796596 0.1543862
#> 
#> Rotation (n x k) = (4 x 4):
#>                      PC1         PC2         PC3        PC4
#> Sepal.Length  0.36138659 -0.65658877  0.58202985  0.3154872
#> Sepal.Width  -0.08452251 -0.73016143 -0.59791083 -0.3197231
#> Petal.Length  0.85667061  0.17337266 -0.07623608 -0.4798390
#> Petal.Width   0.35828920  0.07548102 -0.54583143  0.7536574

prcomp(~Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width, data = iris)
#> Standard deviations (1, .., p=4):
#> [1] 2.0562689 0.4926162 0.2796596 0.1543862
#> 
#> Rotation (n x k) = (4 x 4):
#>                      PC1         PC2         PC3        PC4
#> Sepal.Length  0.36138659 -0.65658877  0.58202985  0.3154872
#> Sepal.Width  -0.08452251 -0.73016143 -0.59791083 -0.3197231
#> Petal.Length  0.85667061  0.17337266 -0.07623608 -0.4798390
#> Petal.Width   0.35828920  0.07548102 -0.54583143  0.7536574
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>